# SQLite - How to access the AUTOINCREMENT value on INSERT?

Tags: sqlite, auto-increment

I have a table with field `ID` being an auto-incrementing `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`. If `ID` is due to be auto-incremented to some integer value `n` on the next `INSERT`, how can I access the value `n` in an `INSERT` statement?

In particular, I sometimes want a row to be initialized with a *negative* `ID`, that is `ID = -n`
(the reason being I am also using `ID` as a boolean flag in addition to a primary key, so that I don't have to create a separate field just for the flag).

Comment: _“I am also using ID as a boolean flag in addition to a primary key, so that I don't have to create a separate field just for the flag”_ – that’s just plain stupid. Don’t do it. Period.

Comment: You shouldn't even attempt to write to a generated key value. Most databases will just ignore it anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Row id generation only kicks in later and not when evaluating the expressions in your SQL. There's `last_insert_rowid()` but no `current_insert_rowid()`.

Also, overloading the rowid to contain other information beyond an identifier doesn't seem like a good idea. Just use other columns for additional information.

Answer (score 1):

As laalto said, you cannot access next value of AUTOINCREMENT, but there's a workaround, if you really need it. Note that this is not an optimal way to do things and it's not thread-safe, so unless you really need it - don't use it.

Given the special treating of "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY" in SQLite we can use:

```
SELECT max(the_column) + 1 FROM table;
```

Then use value returned and put it explicitly when executing INSERT for the PK column.

Note, that this is not the same as using AUTOINCREMENT mechanism itself. The AUTOINCREMENT will always increment the id, while our "workaround" will always use the biggest value at the moment and if you delete all the rows, it will start from 0, while AUTOINCREMENT would continue with numbers where it left.

Reasuming - it's a workaround, don't use it unless you really know what you're doing and you still need it.

Comment: This doesn't work if the last row inserted has been deleted. better to do `UPDATE my_table SET other_id = id WHERE id = last_insert_id();`

Answer (score 0):

Googie's answer doesn't work if the rows on the end of the table are deleted. You can get the autoincrement counter by `SELECT seq FROM sqlite_sequence WHERE name = 'my_table'`

```
INSERT INTO my_table (other_id) VALUES ((SELECT seq FROM sqlite_sequence WHERE name = 'my_table')+1);
```

This is probably not thread safe though. So you can return the row

```
INSERT INTO my_table (other_id) VALUES ((SELECT seq FROM sqlite_sequence WHERE name = 'my_table')+1)
RETURNING *;
```

And `UPDATE` if `other_id != id`.